# Why only custom site columns which contain data will get managed & crawl properties

Tags: search, site-column, crawling, managed-property, crawled-property

i am facing a problem in understanding why some site columns got managed & crawl properties while the other do not. now when i check this further i found that only site columns which have data, will get managed properties created automatically when the crawl runs.

now i am facing this problem.

1. I have a site collection named Depts.
2. Inside this site collection i got 5 sub-sites; `"HR", "Finance", "IT", "Accounting","customer service"`.
3. Inside each sub-site. it got its own site collection site columns. for example the HR sub-site have site columns such as "HR Area", "HR Problem Manager", etc..
4. now i wanted to add a Content Search WebPart. which oversee the 5 sub sites and show items which have the related "Problem Manager" = login user.
5. so i added a new Content Search webpart inside the site collection  home page.
6. then i wanted to reference the related "<<*Dept Name*>> Problem Manager" site column.
7. the problem is that i have noted that only site columns which have data got a managed property under "central admin >> Manage services >> search service >> search schema". but i still want to referecne all the site columns inside my Content search web part. so when users add data the realted items shows inside the web part.

so now not sure how i can overcome these problems:-

1. how i can reference site columns which do not have data and thus do not have managed properties inside my "Content search web part"??
2. Now if manually creating the managed properties inside "central admin >> Manage services >> search service >> search schema" is the way to go . then how i can make sure that the crawl/managed property names are correct. because i got this example; i created a site column using the UI named "`Software Development Risk/Issue owner`" ,, where the site column got the following internal name "`Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Owner`", which is fine.. but its  managed property name inside the search is "`SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSER`" . so seems when building the managed property the white spaces are going to be removed from the site column name + there will be some character truncating... so how i can build my managed properties for the columns that do not have data in this case !!

Comment: For what I remember from my own experience, I haven't had this problem when the site columns had been created on the root level of the site collection.

Comment: @moe but in my case all the site columns i am referring at were created at the site collection root .. but site columns which do not have data ,, does not have any managed properties inside the search .. so can i manually create the managed properties ?

Answer (score 1):

When adding new columns in your SharePoint environment, and wanting to use them in SharePoint Search, they should be indexed first before you can use them.

To have new columns indexed, and thus have them available in search, you should:

- Make sure they have data in them
- Perform a **full** crawl

Columns that do not have any content in them will **not** be indexed if they do not exist in the search index yet. Of course, when they already exist, they will not be removed when the data is cleared.

Easiest approach that we come across, is usually:

- Create the column(s)
- Fill with dummy data
- Perform full crawl
- Remove dummy items

More information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794220.aspx

Comment: this is a workaround i do not want to go with !!! so is manually creating the Managed Properties a valid appraoch to follow?

Comment: Creating properties manually is done buy mapping a **Crawled Property** to a more "user-friendly" name. This crawled property will only exist if the column is crawled at least once. This **only** happens when the column had at least 1 time a value in it, when a **full crawl** was run. I know it's not ideal, but that's simply how the indexer works. The search index only stores actual content. Never *null* values - unfortunately.

Comment: i am trying to get the correct answer to my question.. so you are saying that i can create the managed properties manually ...is this correct ? is Yes then can you chekc my point2 inside my original question ? to see exactly how i can manually build my managed properties names ?

Comment: You can create them manually, but only **after** they have been indexed - and thus a **Crawled** property exists. Then when creating the **Managed** property you can decide yourself what you name it.

Comment: so you are saying that the actual name of the managed property does not have to be related to the site column internal name??,, and what really matters is the name of the   crawled property , which should relative to actual site column name??

Comment: Indeed. You can give it your own managed property name. And you map that property to one or more crawled properties.

Answer (score 1):

Managed Property name doesn't create any affect!
You can create a managed property named ABC for a column named XYZ, what matters is the fact that you do proper mapping of the crawl property to the managed property. You can then set that managed property to be

- Sortable
- Refinable

[This is a blog](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/creating-managed-properties-in-a-site-collection-in-sharepoint-2013/) which guides you to how to create a custom managed property

[Ref](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj219667.aspx#proc5)

Comment: so let me wrap up the final results . now managed properties will not be created until the site columns contain data,and a full crawl runs on the non-empty site columns. so in my case i have to create the managed crawl & managed properties manually.  now the managed properties names can be whatever i want, unlike the managed crawl properties which should relate to the site column.now in my case i have a site column with the following internal name "Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Owner" , and the crawl property for this column is "ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment"

Comment: while the managed properties for it is "SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSERUser".. so this mean if i where to manually create the crawl property for the "Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​er" then i need to apply certain pattern on the site columns , to get its crawl property the pattern is what extract "SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSERUser" from "Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​er" ?? so where i can find this pattern ?

Comment: You are on right track :) Sometimes there are multiple crawl properties created just take care of them.

Comment: Generally crawl property is made like 'ows_InternalColumnName'. But you can refer this article to create via PowerShell https://olafd.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/add-a-crawled-property-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: so now i need to understand first how existing crawl properties relate to site columns.now i have short named site column , for example "NetWrokArea" where its crawl and manged properties are straight forward which are  "ows_q_CHCS_NetworkArea" & "NetworkAreaOWSCHCS" . but when i have a site column with the following internal name "Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​‌​er" how i can know that its related crawl property is "ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment"?? ...

Comment: looks like white spaces (which are encoded inside the internal name  as "_x0020_" ) are being removed , and also the name are going to be truncated .. so my question is how i can understand how sharepoint build the crawl properties names by default ? as this can allow me to understand the relation between existing crawl properties and their site columns + this will allow me to understand how i need to build new crawl properties based on the site columns names ?

Comment: Why don't you create crawled property with powershell as suggested

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but if I may suggest why don't u create internal name of column without space and display name with space! This way your issue will be resolved. Sharepoint behaved strangely with space.

Comment: @Teran now when i create new site columns i always take care about spaces and prevent having long internal names,, but when i start working with sharepoint i was providing names such as "Software Development Risk Issue Own‌​‌​‌​er" through the UI. so that why i am concern about my current column names.. now for example i have 2 site columns with these internal names "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_" & "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_".. but i only got one crawled property which is "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_"

Comment: @Teran and one managed property "_SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSER_".. so this is also a strange behavior,, because currently the two site columns are being treated as one column inside my search. for example if i write the following critiria inside my content search webpart "_SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSER:{User.Name}_" i will get results based on the 2 site columns, "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_" & "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_"..

Comment: so my first question is how the "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_" crawl property was extracted from the internal names? second question is how sharepoint really maps "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_" with the 2 site columns !!

Comment: @johnG one managed property can be clubbed for different site columumns having similar names. If you are concerned about Search provide a filler on content type or list title if required.

Comment: Various crawled property can be clubbed in one managed property.

Comment: @Teran yes i do understand that one manged property can map multiple crawled properties. but seems even one crawl property can cover multiple site column , and these site columns do not necessary have the exact names. for example i have 2 site columns with these INTERNAL names "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​‌​er_" & "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_",, where these 2 site columns got the same crawl property which is "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_" and the same managed property which is  "_SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSERUser_".

Comment: @Teran so my first question is how the "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_" crawl property was extracted from the site columns internal names? second question. when i write the following inside my Content Search web part "_SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSERUser:{User.Name}_" i got results from the two site columns,, so how did sharepoint recognize that the managed property which is map to the same crawl property is referring two site columns , that have different internal names?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on top of the answers above. In your scenario the best possible solution for your Problem managers site column is to create manually or using Powershell one custom managed property let's say "**ProblemManager**" and map it to crawled properties of all the 5 site column for problem managers. Now this managed property will always contain the data for HR or IT or Finance problem manager depending on from which site the result was returned.
[image]

The advantage here is in your content search webpart query you just have to specify  "**ProblemManager:{User.Name}**" to get the results from all the 5 sites where current user is the problem manager.

Comment: now i can manage this problem as you mentioned. but currently i am trying to understand how the managed/crawl properties were mapped to my current site columns. For example i have 2 site columns with these INTERNAL names "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​‌​er_" & "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_",, where these 2 site columns got the same crawl property which is "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_" and the same managed property which is  "_SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSERUser_".

Comment: so my first question is how the "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_" crawl property was extracted from the 2 site columns internal names and produce the same crawl property name? second question. when i write the following inside my Content Search web part "_SoftwareDevelopmentOWSUSERUser:{User.Name}_" i got results from the two site columns,, so how did sharepoint recognize that the managed property which is map to the same crawl property is referring two site columns  that have different internal names?

Comment: No SharePoint does not map different internal name site column into same crawled property.

Comment: but based on my test and also in my case the 2 site columns which have their internal names as "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Risk_x002F_Issue_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​‌​‌​er_" & "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_Own‌​‌​‌​er_",, got the same crawl property which is "_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_". also these two site columns will have the same internal names on the list level (when i access a list that have these 2 site column) their internal names were "_Software_x0020_Development_x0020_" but of course still they have different siteid.

Comment: also when i used the single managed property which is linked to a single crawl property inside my search content type i will get results from the 2 site columns... so in my case the 2 site columns got the same internal names at the list level + they got a single crawl property + a single managed property.

Comment: my understanding that i got this conflict because my site columns internal names are some how long,, and when sharepoint builds the crawl/managed properties it will not only remove white spaces but also will apply some character truncating ,, and since my 2 site columns have the exact characters at the beginning so this results in a single crawl/managed property representing 2 different site columns !! what do you think about this?

Comment: This could well be a reason, i have never came across this scenario. Best way for you in this create is to manually create managed properties and map each one to the correct crawled property instead of using the automatically created one.

Comment: but again i am saying i only have one crawl property representing the 2 site columns !!!

Comment: You can keep the internal names short let's say "SDRiskIssueOwner" and "SDOwner" , so that you could avoid the confusion and keep the long ones as display name of the site column

Comment: so in my case there is no advantage of having 2 managed properties ,, as i only have one crawl property for 2 site columns..

Comment: from now on i always keep the site columns as short as possible,, but i am trying to understand what is happening inside my site collection now ???

Comment: 1 crawled property for 2 different site columns is always a bad idea. So you should try to overcome that by keeping your site column internal names short

Comment: so you mean i need to rename my site columns internal names? is this possible using powrshell ? second question how is SP recognizing the relation between the crawled property and its 2 site columns? as the crawl property name ("_ows_q_USER_SoftwareDevelopment_") is just a subset of the complete site columns internal names. . weird is it ?

Comment: You cannot change the internal name of the site column. you should recreate those site columns with short names

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure do you refer to Sharepoint on premise or online, but to my knowledge Managed property are not created automatically. The process usually is

1. Create site column, create some content with this column (list item, document item)
2. Crawl the content, after crawl you should have crawled property available.
3. Then you create new managed property and map it to the crawled property.

This works well for couple of columns, but if you work on project then it may not be most efficient. You can create both crawled and managed properties using powershell, then you are not worried about column contains data:

New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataCrawledProperty (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608064.aspx)

New-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff608089.aspx)

Here you have example how to bind them together in a script:
http://blog.kuppens-switsers.net/sharepoint/creating-managed-crawled-properties-using-powershell/

Comment: Actually managed properties *are* created automatically (sp2013 +). https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Good to know, moved to SP2013 only recently so still finding out the differences, thanks for sharing @Bunzab.

Comment: @MarekSarad i have never created any managed properties manully in SP 2013 .. and i am using on-primise